# How to implement features(e.g. ERC721OrdersFeature) into 0x proxy

Tags: 0x, proxy-contracts

I want to integrate with 0x-protocol v4 for trading ERC20 Token <-> ERC721 Token & ERC1155 Token, and I want to deploy it myself.

I have deployed [0xProxy](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x8f6de0bb0c5e0bfd693fc0a37ee8948b66853628), [0x Proxy Governor](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xaf0e27cbac5ddd61ec3abd7c7de85e5ea214584f), and [other features](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xa80465928faf190899f28d971f69158e15e267d5) as well.

As far as I understand, 0xProxy does not have any implementation, so I need to implement functions myself. I need to call Governor's submitTransaction & executeTransaction to delegatecall migrate function in 0xProxy, and the migrate function in 0xProxy will delegatecall another migrate function in ERC721OrdersFeature, so it will _registerFeatureFunction into 0xProxy ([txLink](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xc85effce2f28ea447f6cc48548b993a81c86fbc469934318bcceaed3a6941638)) (if it's not work at that way, please correct me).

But when I copy the data and put my addresses into it, it doesn't work well ([txLink](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x2db2630688be442c88a2524d01ebc121728e59bb217a30abd353d0126935627c)).
I am wondering which part did I get wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not using the Governor contract for the deployment, and simply using your EOA as the contract owner (this simplifies things a bit).

The steps are as follows:

1. Deploy the [InitialMigration contract](https://github.com/0xProject/protocol/blob/development/contracts/zero-ex/contracts/src/migrations/InitialMigration.sol). In the constructor, you can use your EOA as the `initializeCaller_`.
2. Deploy ZeroEx contract. In the constructor, use the InitialMigration contract address as the `bootstrapper`.
3. Deploy the feature contracts. In addition to ERC721OrdersFeature and whatnot, you'll need [SimpleFunctionRegistryFeature](https://github.com/0xProject/protocol/blob/development/contracts/zero-ex/contracts/src/features/SimpleFunctionRegistryFeature.sol) and [OwnableFeature](https://github.com/0xProject/protocol/blob/development/contracts/zero-ex/contracts/src/features/OwnableFeature.sol).
4. Call `InitialMigration.initializeZeroEx(yourAddress, zeroExAddress, {registry, ownable})`. See [here](https://github.com/0xProject/protocol/blob/development/contracts/zero-ex/contracts/src/migrations/InitialMigration.sol#L61)
5. Now the [migrate](https://github.com/0xProject/protocol/blob/development/contracts/zero-ex/contracts/src/features/OwnableFeature.sol#L90) function is registered to the proxy. Call `ZeroEx.migrate` for each feature contract (other than SimpleFunctionRegistryFeature and OwnableFeature). This call will usually look like this: `ZeroEx.migrate(erc721OrdersFeature.address, 0x8fd3ab80, yourEOA)`. Most features' `migrate` function don't take any arguments so we pass in `0x8fd3ab80` as the second argument, which is the function selector for `migrate()`.

Note that depending on the ERC721/ERC1155 token that you're testing with, you may need [ERC165Feature](https://github.com/0xProject/protocol/blob/development/contracts/zero-ex/contracts/src/features/ERC165Feature.sol). This contract doesn't have a `migrate` function, since it only exposes a single function. Instead, you would call `ZeroEx.extend(0x01ffc9a7, erc165Feature.address)` to register the `supportsInterface` function.

Comment: Thanks very much!! It works fine.